# Failed DEM via Natural Neighbor in QGIS 2.14.2-Essen

Tags: qgis, raster, dem, google-earth, saga

Following the indications of Monde Geospatial (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bLbY3iMBW-A) I created a CSV file with the altitudinal data (Google Earth) for 2182 total points and imported it into QGIS 2.14.2-Essen. I am stalled at the next step: DEM generation. The message "The following layers were not correctly generated. Grid" appears on the Natural Neighbour log console. Before the failed output and as the process is underway, I observed a "Can´t load requested DLL" appearing in the same console. I need help identifying the cause and, if necessary, seeking alternatives to Monde Geospatial´s method.
[image: Failed DEM message]

Answer (score 1):

I get an error meassage that `MrSID.dll` can not be found, but it is not needed for Geotiff output, and I get the expected raster result:

[image]

Your project CRS is EPSG:4326, so the grid cell size should be in degrees. The default of 100 might be nonsense.

Comment: I followed Monde Geospatial´s instructions and replaced the default of 100 with 0.0005. Is this a reasonable cell size?

Comment: I noticed that some algorithms don't work properly if the units are degrees. Maybe because some internal values don't like small cellsizes. Try the same in a UTM CRS.